# Xcode Cocoa Simulator Gone?

Tags: xcode6

Haven't found anything about where the Cocoa Simulator went.

I'm trying to simulate an OS X app UI without building/running.

Any way in Xcode 6 to load just the nib file to interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the assistant editor. Use the navigation button in the jump bar to preview xib and storyboard files in the assistant editor.

[image]

**UPDATE**

To get the preview to appear, you must open the xib or storyboard file in both assistant editors. Use the navigation button in the bottom or right editor, depending on how you stack the editors, to preview the interface.

Comment: This doesn't simulate the UI.
EDIT: Preview is non functional

Comment: I couldn't get it to show anything either. But there's no other way to preview an interface in Xcode 6. The Simulate Document menu item was removed in Xcode 6. Read the section "Previewing Your Layout for Different Localizations, iOS Devices, and iOS Versions" in the Interface Builder Help document for more information. The Interface Builder Help document is part of Xcode's documentation.

Comment: Okay. If I click on Assistant Editor(interlocking rings icon) in the right pane, then click on the first name in the *jump bar*, then use the pop up menu to navigate to MainMenu.xib, then click on the four square icon on the far left in your image, I see the drop down menu in your image--including the Preview line, but clicking on Preview displays a blank white pane with the words "No Selection".

Answer (score 1):

in xcode 5 you could simulate your document (editor -> simulate document), seems that this menu item is gone :/

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name "*Simulator"
```

export your xib to a nib file and run:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface\ Builder/Plug-ins/CocoaPlugin.ibplugin/Contents/Resources/IBCocoaSimulator.app/Contents/MacOS/IBCocoaSimulator "path to nib-file"
```

Comment: Yep,  in Xcode 6.2 your `find` command reveals that the Cocoa Simulator is right where you said it is. And, your Cocoa Simulator command works for me  (crashes and burns with a path to the .xib file, but after converting to a .nib file, cleanly launches the Cocoa Simulator version 4.3). But why is Apple burying the Cocoa Simulator deep in Xcode's directory structure? For those that don't know this trick: you can export the .xib file (as a .nib file) to your Desktop, then paste the path to the Cocoa Simulator into a Terminal window, then type a space...

Comment: ...then drag the .nib file on your Desktop onto the Terminal window--and it's *path* will be entered in the Terminal window at the point of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Preview to work in Xcode 6, however as far as I can tell it's useless because you can't resize the window. Here's how:

1) In the Project Navigator pane (on the left side of the Xcode window), select MainMenu.xib.  That will display the menu bar in Interface Builder in the middle pane.

2) In the Xcode menu bar, click on `View>Assistant Editor>Show Assistant Editor`.  (Or, you can open the Assistant Editor by clicking on the interlocking rings icon at the far right at the top of the Xcode editor window).

3) At the top of the Assistant Editor pane there are some forward and back arrows.  To the right of the arrows is a *jump bar*, which shows directory and file names separated by right arrows.  If you click on the first name in the jump bar(you may see some automatic sliding happen to reveal the first name), the *Assistant Editor pop-up menu* will be revealed.  In the pop-up menu, click on `Preview>MainMenu.xib`.  If you don't succeed in clicking on the first name in the jump bar, you won't see the Preview choice in the pop-up menu.

If you see a completely blank screen for the preview(mine actually displays English in the bottom right corner), then in the Interface Builder pane select the icon that represents your MainMenu.xib file--it's usually the icon at the bottom.  The preview should display in the Assistant Editor pane.

It's also possible to navigate to your MainMenu.xib file in the Assistant Editor pop-up menu and select it.  If I do that, the Assistant Editor pane still displays a blank window, but with the object icons aligned down the left hand side.  In that case, if I select the icon for MainMenu.xib(i.e. I select the icon in the Assistant Editor pane rather than in the Interface Builder pane), the preview appears.